# How to create .cdx file from .dbf file in pyhton?

Tags: python, visual-foxpro, dbf

import dbf

## open file

table = dbf.Table(str("/art_gr.dbf"))

## open table

table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)

## add data to table

table.append({'DENUMIRE': '2', 'COD': '3'})

## open cdx file

index = dbf.Idx(filename='C:/SAGA C.3.0/salv_bd/0001/art_gr.cdx', table=table)

#how can i update the index with new data??

## close table

table.close()

I want to update an existing .cdx file with data inserted in .dbf file

Comment: If it is a structural index file (name is same as the table as it is in your case), then you don't need to open it separately and it updates as you modify the data. If it is not structural, you need to specify it as the controlling index and yet it updates automatically as you modify the data. Non-structural indexes are not used maybe for over 2 decades.

Comment: The .cdx file doesn't update when modifying data in the .dbf file. I use an accounting program that queries by the .cdx file. If I append some data to the .dbf file, that data won't be updated in the program. I need a solution to update the .cdx file somehow.

Comment: Well that is how structural indexes work in VFP. Probably the problem is with that dbf.Table() that you are using. Provided you use something like OLEDB, it would just update fine.  I don't understand what " that queries by the .cdx file." means. Isn't there a way in python to make and use an OLEDB connection.

Answer (score 1):

My python `dbf` library doesn't support index files at this time.  If no other means of updating the `.cdx` index file is available, you'll need to rebuild the indices in the accounting program.